# Error in insert query in doctrine migration

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following query which is running perfectly fine.

```
insert into `mytable` values('it','{
            
    "my_page": "e avete domande, inviate un''e-mail a ",
    "final_file_name": "Ifirmato",
        "zipFile_Name": "Files allegati"
}\')');
```

`un''e-mail` in `final_page` property is giving error. I put 2 single quotes because one single quote is part of the value. In the standalone query, it is working. But inside the method, it is giving an error.

[image]

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: `inviate un''e-mail a "` You are inside of a single-quoted string, so you'll need to escape the quotes just like you have the others

Comment: You would be better off parameterizing this query and using json_encode on the JSON blob. Something like `$this->addSql('insert into translations values(:it, :json)', array(':it' => 'it', 'json' => json_encode(array('footer_header' => 'Contattaci'....))));`

Comment: @aynber can you give just an example please?

Comment: @user3783243 I did not understood. this is inside the migration file to add static data. can we do something to handle that quote issue?

Comment: The parameterizing would resolve the quoting issue. The documentation shows support for that, https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/1.7/reference/migration_classes.html. I'm not familiar with migration file, but if it is generating like this it is dangerous.

Comment: You've got examples all over your code already, such as `values(\'it\'`